# Angular 2 Custom Template CSS Issue + Event Binding

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm having an issue with CSS due to the way I have to bind the click event in a custom template. So I have a component that basically outputs a list with the items' templates being defined in the "parent component".

**Reusable List Component with custom template**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-list',
    template: `
        <span *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="pickItem(item)">
            <template
                ngFor let-number [ngForOf]="[card]"
                [ngForTemplate]="itemTmpl"
            ></template>
        </span>
    `
})

export class MyListComponent {
    @Input() items: Item[];
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTmpl: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
    @Output() onItemPick = new EventEmitter<Item>();

    pickItem(item: Item) {
        item.picked = !item.picked;
        if (item.picked) {
            console.log('Item was picked!')
        } else {
            console.log('Item was unpicked!');
        }

        this.onItemPick.emit(item);
    }
}
```

**Using the List Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'shopping-list',
    template: `
        <my-list [items]="itemsList">
            <template let-temp>
                <span [class.picked]="temp.picked">
                    {{ temp.name }}
                </span>
            </template>
        </my-list>
    `
})

export class ShoppingListComponent {
    itemsList: Item[] = [
        new Item('Apples'),
        new Item('Bananas'),
        new Item('Carrots')
    ];
}
```

As you can see above in the `my-list` component I'm wrapping the templates that are received by a `span`. The only reason I'm doing so is to allow me to bind the `pickItem()` click event to the template.

**CSS Issue**

The above component results in the following HTML:

```
<shopping-list>
    <my-list>
        <span>
            <span class="picked">
                Apples
            </span>
        </span>
        <span>
            <span>
                Bananas
            </span>
        </span>
        <span>
            <span>
                Carrots
            </span>
        </span>
    </my-list>
</shopping-list>
```

In the `shopping-list` component CSS I have a `margin-bottom: 10px` for the list items, however I'd like the `last-child` to have `margin-bottom: 0` which I cannot do using `last-child` or using CSS in the `my-list` component. From what I've tried it seems that I cannot achieve this through CSS since I have a "wrapper" span around the template.

I think the ideal solution would be that the custom templates are not generated with a "wrapper" element but in that case I'm not sure how I can bind the click event. Is there a way to tackle this in a different way?

**Update**

This is an example on plunker of the issue I have: https://plnkr.co/edit/djq2fWYkw4EhjYhD24nb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use your existing html and the direct descendant and last-child css selectors to achieve the desired result.

## CSS

```
my-list > span:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

#### Snippit

```css
my-list > span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span.picked {
  background: #9999FF;
}
my-list > span {
  display: block;
}
shopping-list {
  background: #55FF55;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<shopping-list>
  <my-list>
    <span>
            <span class="picked">
                Apples
            </span>
    </span>
    <span>
            <span>
                Bananas
            </span>
    </span>
    <span>
            <span>
                Carrots
            </span>
    </span>
  </my-list>
</shopping-list>
```

## Edit 1

You can just update your global styles to achieve the desired result. If you are looking to modify only the component's css then I would recommend using the shadow-dom piercing opperater, `>>>` or `/deep/`. A third option would be to pass in an input parameter to the component indicating that it is the last child and then applying conditional stylings with the `ngClass` directive.

### Using global styles

```
my-list > span:last-child > span{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

#### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/djq2fWYkw4EhjYhD24nb?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it didn't work. I'm guessing it's because it's in Angular and the way it handles the CSS. For sure your solution is fine, but the example is in "plain HTML" so to speak. I'll update my question with what Angular is rendering exactly.

Comment: Agreed :) Thanks for your update... since I wanted to keep the CSS in the same component I've opted for the shadow-dom piercing operator using the following CSS rule: `my-list >>> span:last-child > span { ... }`